# Set balloonText in Javascript Amchart

Tags: amcharts

I am using javascript Amchart. I need to set the balloonText like

```
  if value is "1" means "1 point" as balloonText , 
  if more than one means(Ex:5), "5 points " as balloonText .
```

Can anyone help me to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign user defined text in the hover balloon by defining a variable in your data array like below.

```
var d = {
    date: new Date(year_s,mon_s,date_s,hr_s,min_s,sec_s),
    customBullet: "round",
    balloonTextField: value+" points"
};
```

Then you have to assign the newly created variable into the graph like below.

```
graph.balloonText = "[[balloonTextField]]";
chart.addGraph(graph);
```